# Why some fonts don't render on some android stock browsers?

Tags: android, css, fonts

Why do some fonts render on some stock android browsers and not other stock android browsers?  For example, I bought the Have a Nice Day font from myfonts.com and unzipped the package here:

http://jl.evermight.com/myfont/StartHere.html

The font appears fine on my friend's S3, but it appears as Arial on my Galaxy Note (version 1).  I upgraded my Galaxy Note OS to 4.0.4.   So it's not that old.

What can I do to my css, or webserver, or html code etc... to force the font to render properly on all modern android stock browers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed. Apparently there was a bug on myfonts.com that corrupted my font files. I contacted myfonts.com and they corrected the issue right away. Then re-sent me the font files. Now everything works perfectly.

The guys at myfonts.com are amazing. Very good customer + tech support services.